# Server "wait" time is too much on web domain

Tags: php, sql, dns, wait, timing

Well i have been working on my client-server app locally and everything was ok. Yesterday i've tried to upload it on a web domain and i realized that when a request is sent it lasts more or less 5 seconds to receive an answer from the server.

Using the google chrome console i checked that this delay is given by "waiting", and not by "sending" or "receiving" the data, so i suppose that the server lasts 5 seconds to run the PHP code. How is it possible? on my computer php cod is run in a few of milliseconds

Comment: need more information about the server. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the times mean in Google Chrome's timeline in the network panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537399/what-does-the-times-mean-in-google-chromes-timeline-in-the-network-panel) - The answer to that question exactly tells you what makes this possible. Also, please run a desktop sesssion on the server you copied the code to so that you actually can compare your local desktop session requesting the PHP code from the same computer to the remove desktop session requesting the PHP code from the same computer. Otherwise there are too much interference metrics.

Comment: Or in other words: You need to find out your own which computer, process and then finally line of code is causing the delay: a) some computer in the network used to access the remote computer. b) the remote computer itself c) some server-software on the remote computer d) your own script in the different environment e) some service or resource your script is using when running from that remote computer. As you can see this can be a lot which is why before asking such a question you need to do some metrics and pin-point your issue a bit.