# OpenCart 1.5.6.1 with 400.000 products

Tags: time, load, opencart

I have opencart based webshop with more than 400.000 products on-board. And there is a problem. Then i enter in any page, load speed is very good, max 3 sec.
But when i enter in home page, next click on any link in this web is taking a minute to load.
There is no any product models at home page installed. And there is the link of website: http://1.multimod.lt

Comment: I believe you have to start by reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733272/388382

Comment: Well, since the first request/response (when loading the homepage) is done in a few seconds (1-2) and each other is taking minutes, I'd suspect the server (hosting provider) itself... If You have the possibility to upload Your site somewhere else (just for a try), do it and watch the loading times there...

Comment: I've been trying to use this shop on other server, result was the same. Every page loads per few seconds, unless it was entered from homepage. Page loading per minute exactly after visiting homepage.
Also, same result is on the localhost

Comment: Are you trying to load content (data!?) from an external domain?

Comment: no, all data is on one server.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling mysql slow query logs on your server.

Then look at the logs after you try to load the index - it might help show what queries are taking a long time (if that is the cause)