# The meaning of Blocking in Chrome console -> Network -> Timing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently I have noticed that Chrome browser has Timing tab in the Network section.

This tab has the following elements:

- Blocking
- Sending
- Waiting
- Receiving

For example here is a screenshot for SO:
[image]

Also I think I know what sending, waiting and receiving means, I have no idea what Blocking means.

So what blocking means? What does it block and what makes these numbers smaller/bigger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the times mean in Google Chrome's timeline in the network panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537399/what-does-the-times-mean-in-google-chromes-timeline-in-the-network-panel)

Comment: This is something that answers this:              https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Answer (score 3):

'Blocking' is the time difference between the HTTP request being ready to be sent and actually being sent. Formal definition [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing).

Why wasn't the request sent when it was ready to be sent? There could be multiple reasons for that, e.g.

1. The maximum number of TCP connections that the browser could open are all busy processing some other requests. E.g. Chrome opens upto 6 TCP connections per server/proxy. So this request has to wait till one of them gets free. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) for other browsers.
2. Proxy negotiation may be required for sending the request.
3. The machine running the browser may be slow or overloaded. So although the request is ready, it is busy doing something else.