# Why are there gaps in Chrome Inspector's static resources?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, browser

Can someone explain what gaps in Google Chrome Inspector's Network tab represent?

The network tab shows a list of consecutively loaded resources. For the most part they overlay and/or immediately follow one another. But sometimes there is a gap, and in the case of this screenshot there's actually almost 2 seconds of a gap.

All 5 of the later loaded scripts are hosted by a third party.

[image: Google Chrome Network]

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the heading "Timeline" and then select "Duration", you'll get a better view of what's actually happening for each request.

If you hover over each line, you'll see a breakdown of each request, and most likely for those later ones you'll find that they have large "Blocking" values.

Edit: I should probably put a small note about what blocking is here, just in case. Blocking (as defined in the link in the next paragraph) `is the amount of time between the UI thread starting the request and the HTTP GET request getting onto the wire.`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537399/what-does-the-times-mean-in-google-chromes-timeline-in-the-network-panel) is a good Stack Overflow question that explains what each segment means and what you can (or can't) do to improve it.